# Python Code-While loop never end

Tags: python, python-3.x, while-loop, revitpythonshell

I am new to Python.Trying to learn it.
This is my Code:

```
import sys
my_int=raw_input("How many integers?")
try:
    my_int=int(my_int)
except ValueError:
    ("You must enter an integer")
ints=list()
count=0
while count<my_int:
    new_int=raw_input("Please enter integer{0}:".format(count+1))
    isint=False
    try:
        new_int=int(new_int)
    except:
        print("You must enter an integer")
    if isint==True:
        ints.append(new_int)
        count+=1
```

The code is executing but the loop is always repeating and is not allowing  me to enter 2nd integer.

Output:

```
How many integers?3
Please enter integer1:1
Please enter integer1:2
Please enter integer1:3
Please enter integer1:
```

Can i know what is wrong with my code?
Thank you

Comment: `if isint==True` - when would it ever be True?

Comment: Why do you need the boolean check? Just put all the code that you need when an int in the `try`

Answer (score 4):

The problem of your code is that `isint` is never changed and is always `False`, thus `count` is never changed. I guess your intention is that when the input is a valid integer, increase the `count`;otherwise, do nothing to `count`.

Here is the code, `isint` flag is not need:

```
import sys

while True:
    my_int=raw_input("How many integers?")
    try:
        my_int=int(my_int)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("You must enter an integer")
ints=list()
count=0
while count<my_int:
    new_int=raw_input("Please enter integer{0}:".format(count+1))
    try:
        new_int=int(new_int)
        ints.append(new_int)
        count += 1
    except:
        print("You must enter an integer")
```

Answer (score 1):

isint needs to be updated after asserting that the input was int

**UPDATE:**
There is another problem on the first try-except. If the input wasn't integer, the program should be able to exit or take you back to the begining. The following will keep on looping until you enter an integer first

```
ints=list()

proceed = False
while not proceed:
    my_int=raw_input("How many integers?")
    try:
        my_int=int(my_int)
        proceed=True
    except:
        print ("You must enter an integer")

count=0
while count<my_int:
    new_int=raw_input("Please enter integer{0}:".format(count+1))
    isint=False
    try:
        new_int=int(new_int)
        isint=True
    except:
        print("You must enter an integer")
    if isint==True:
        ints.append(new_int)
        count+=1
```

Comment: How many integers?3
Please enter integer1:1
Please enter integer2:2
Please enter integer3:3

Comment: How many integers?3
Please enter integer1:1
Please enter integer2:2
Please enter integer3:3

Now its running perfectly
Thank you Man.
I Thank everyone for helping me.

Answer (score 0):

A better code:

```
import sys
my_int=raw_input("How many integers?")
try:
    my_int=int(my_int)
except ValueError:
    ("You must enter an integer")
ints = []


for count in range(0, my_int):

    new_int=raw_input("Please enter integer{0}:".format(count+1))
    isint=False

    try:

        new_int=int(new_int)
        isint = True

    except:

        print("You must enter an integer")

    if isint==True:
        ints.append(new_int)
```